# Android. Synchronization of listeners for dependent objects

Tags: android, listview, listener, adapter

I am struggling with "synchronisation" of two listeners for two objects, which are dependent on each other.

Suppose we have a `ListView list` and a scrollable `LinearLayout slider`. Both are in a layout within a `Fragment`.

When I scroll list to some item, slider should `autoscroll` to show the corresponding position.
When I scroll the slider, then the list should `smoothScrollToPosition` and show the corresponding position.

Thus, I have

```
interface SliderListener {
    public onPositionChanged();
}
```

and

```
interface ListViewListener {
    public onListPositionChanged();
}
```

If I just implement these two methods in a common controller (I implement them in a controller `Fragment`), then there will be a deadlock (they endlessly try to scroll each other and generate more and more events).

I tried to use some simple boolean semaphore variable and check it's state before doing actions, but it still results in concurrency.

What is a proper way to synchronize the listeners usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did create recursive logic loops for events:

```
A re-positioned --> scroll B= r-epositioning B --> scroll A (re-postioned) --> .....
```

Because your `Listeners` are all **passive responsive actions** for events (resulting functions), you cannot control these resulting actions **not to produce** events.

You must change your **boolean semaphore variable** value in your intercepting event handling functions (as `onTouch()` or `onScoll()` or something like that)

Comment: `synchronized` is for preventing job from being intercepted while executing in case of working with multiple threads.